# UiPath Orchestrator - Scheduled Jobs Get Stuck In "Pending" State

Tags: rpa, uipath

I have a scheduled UiPath job that keeps getting stuck in the 'pending' state in Orchestrater and never runs. I notice that the Robot has Fatal Alerts saying "#robot [name] disconnected." The temporary fix seems to be to restart the machine the robot is running on. The job then will run.

Are these things related?

Has anyone else experienced this and found a more permanent fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this exact same problem and asked the very same question in the official [UiPath Forums](https://forum.uipath.com/t/must-reconnect-assistant-to-get-robots-to-execute-as-pending-allocation-status-haunts-orchestrator/248093/3).

[image]

### Replicating the problem

Here is what I found when I investigated [UiPath](https://www.rpacertified.com/cert-questions-answers.html) further:

- The robot was created as a Studio or Studio Pro robot. This is a problem as support for these types of robots is ending/has ended.
- The robot would run not just on rebooting the machine, but specifically when disconnecting and reconnecting UiPath Assistant. If I bounced the assistant it would run once and only once, and the successful execution would show in the UiPath Orchestrator jobs window
- The process would only run if the "Run at startup" toggle was enabled. If the "Run at Startup" toggle was turned off, it would not run at all

If you can replicate that behavior, then we had the exact same problem.

### How to fix the pending state problem

Rather than set the robot up as a Studio or StudioPro type, create an [unattended UiPath robot](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Create-your-first-RPA-robot-to-UiPath-Orchestrator-tutorial). Then, when you go to run the [UiPath Orchestrator Process](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-create-a-UiPath-Orchestrator-process-to-run-your-RPA-robots), chose the unattended robot as the execution target. It should run without sticking in the pending state.

[image: Unattended Robot]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this things are related. When the robot is disconnected the job will be in status "Pending" until the robot is connected again and then it's gonna run.

As for why the robot get's disconnected - there may be many reasons why it's getting disconnected, but this is mostly caused by the machine itself, e.g. because you're behind the firewall or the UiRobot service is being stopped after some time. To check what's happening you'll need to investigate events on that machine, so you can see when and why it's stopping the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's not running because it can't connect to the bot. Have you tried submitting a ticket with UiPath?

Comment: Yes, no resolution thus far